# Cannot import gi from PyGi in Spyder

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder, pygobject

I primarily use python for scientific computing and have become quite accustomed to Spyder. I am working on a mutlimedia project and would like to use the Gstreamer bindings for python. The best way I could find to install Gstreamer on Windows was through PyGi.

Now the problem, `import gi` works fine in both python and Ipython loaded in a command prompt. However, trying to do the same in Spyder results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-a23efdcdbcd8>", line 1, in <module>
    import gi

  File "C:\Users\Conner\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\gi\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I made sure the interpreter was the same and added `C:\Users\Conner\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages` to the PYTHONPATH to no avail.

I could develop it outside of Spyder but I am damn stubborn and I don't like when things don't work.